# Opening a Microsoft Office File in Sharepoint is taking too much time

Tags: document, 2016, office-integration

We are accessing SharePoint 2016 sites through VDI(External Virtual Client Machines) which has Microsoft office 2010 installed . When any user uploads an office file(Excel , Word , PPT) on SharePoint site and then try to open that file by clicking the file , it is taking approx 1~2 minutes and showing "Connecting to Server" message .

Same things happened when user try to access the sites through laptops having Microsoft office 2013 installed on it .

Earlier we thought that the issue can be caused due to Mismatch between Microsoft SharePoint version and Microsoft office version but for Development Environment , its working fine . This problem is mainly caused on Pre-Production Environment .

Comment: Any kind of help will be appreciable .